# I have 2 different bar charts with a common X axis and 2 different Y axis. I want to combine those 2 graphs using the X axis into one using python

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, bar-chart

[image: First image]

Code for the first image:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.bar(data, x='date', y='oi_diff_nifty15800CE',title='Oi chain of Nifty 15800CE')
fig.update_layout(width=650,height=500)
fig.show()
```

[image: Second Image]

Code for second image:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.bar(data, x='date', y='oi_diff_nifty15800PE',title='Oi chain of Nifty 15800PE') 
fig.update_layout(width=650,height=500)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

- you really need to state what you are trying to achieve beyond combining
- have simulated **data**
- two approaches here

  1. use `add_traces()` to add traces from one figure to another figure
  2. just change `px.bar()` parameters so it is generated as a single **figure**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# simulate data...
data = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range("21-jun-2021", periods=2),
        "oi_diff_nifty15800CE": np.random.randint(5, 15, 2),
        "oi_diff_nifty15800PE": np.random.randint(5, 15, 2),})

fig = px.bar(data, x="date", y="oi_diff_nifty15800CE", title="Oi chain of Nifty 15800CE")
# build from two different figures
fig.update_layout(width=650, height=300).add_traces(
    px.bar(data, x="date", y="oi_diff_nifty15800PE", title="Oi chain of Nifty 15800PE").data).show()

# just change params...
px.bar(data, x="date", y=["oi_diff_nifty15800PE","oi_diff_nifty15800CE"], barmode="group").update_layout(width=650, height=300).show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, Thanks for replying. Actually, I was trying to create an option chain for call and put options of stock data in which I wanted to merge these two graphs and display the call and put graph side by side.

Comment: I was not able to understand which parameters are you talking about which I need to change in px.bar() can you please specify?

Comment: from your comment,  I believe what you want is defining **y** as a list rather than a string.  second example in code